# How do I clone custom HTTP Request Header Variables to the Response in IIS6?

Tags: http-headers, iis-6, httprequest, httpresponse, siteminder

I am currently working on a website where an authentication service (SiteMinder in this case) is forwarding a user's HTTP request on successful authentication to IIS6 while adding several custom HTTP header variables.  Is there a way in IIS6 to clone (echo) these HTTP header variables and return them to the client as HTTP response header variables?

I am ultimately needing the equivalent of the Apache module mod_headers' "echo" command, detailed here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has a good write up on working with HTTP header variables in IIS6.

[HOWTO: Retrieve Request Headers using ISAPI, ASP, and ASP.Net](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/04/20/howto-retrieve-request-headers-using-isapi-asp-and-asp-net.aspx)